# magento2 custom product attribute acl permission how to?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, acl

```
protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Mageants_AdvancedPermissions::catalog_attributes_attributes');
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more clearer on what you are additionally trying to acheive so can advise better